# why we need 3d or even 4d Texture?

Tags: opengl, graphics, opengl-es, directx, 3d

usually we use image to texture map to surface? recently I heard there is 3d texture or even 4d texture, I am wondering why there is 3d-4d texture? How to map them to the surface.

Since surface is 2d concept, how to map 3d or 4d object to 2d? Any reason behind?

Is there any 3d texture images available to try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that in the end, a 2D image is mapped onto a surface. However, 3D textures allow interpolation between 3-dimensional texture coordinates inside that 3D texture.

This may be helpful:
http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:3D_Textures

Comment: To add: You have 2D array textures, but you can only interpolate (filter) between mipmap levels of an array slice, not between the array slices. 3D allows you to interpolate between the depth slices.

Answer (score 0):

I think that 4d also has a time component, it is time varying, it is more like a special effect than anything else, it is the same as the 3d texture except animated. currently standard animated textures take too much memory among other things.

A 3d texture is great for example if you want to model a vase  which is made of marble, the stone is a 3d turbulent structure, and if you can apply the 3d stone onto shape of a vase it looks better than 2d version.